# Data not inserted in DB from JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am storing data from Json to db. some rows[]elements[] are inserting but thats a random call.
after every refresh either 1st obj is only stored, sometimes 2 elements.
in query all the data is going right but not executing

[This is the JSON file, I only want data from row[i]element[i] in diagonal.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVT2I.png)

[This is the data I gathered from JSON file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVncz.png)

[This is the data passing to the query but not inserted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACCDO.png)

I only want data in diagonal from  row[i]element[i].

```
<?php
$url1 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header("Refresh: 1800; URL=$url1");
try {
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=distancejson', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {die();}
mysql_error());
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=33.712515,73.051294|33.704902,73.057019|33.697274,73.062723|33.689659,73.068459|33.682035,73.074173|33.674414,73.079879|33.666776,73.085611|33.659143,73.091299|33.651526,73.097076|33.643880,73.102775&destinations=33.704902,73.057019|33.697274,73.062723|33.689659,73.068459|33.682035,73.074173|33.674414,73.079879|33.666776,73.085611|33.659143,73.091299|33.651526,73.097076|33.643880,73.102775|33.636243,73.108493&mode=driving&departure_time=now&key=AIzaSyBmRTOahiTFM83GPiTUGo7NWTFbmL0U3yw';

$jsondata = json_decode(json_encode(file_get_contents($url)), true);

$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$size = sizeof($data);
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
echo "<br>";
for ($j = $i; $j < 10; $j++) {
    $intervalnumber = 1 + $i;
    $destination_addresses = $data['destination_addresses'][$j];
    $origin_addresses = $data['origin_addresses'][$j];
    $distance = $data['rows'][$i]['elements'][$j]['distance']['value'];
    $duration = $data['rows'][$i]['elements'][$j]['duration']['value'];
    $duration_in_traffic_text = $data['rows'][$i]['elements'][$j]['duration_in_traffic']['text'];
    $duration_in_traffic_value = $data['rows'][$i]['elements'][$j]['duration_in_traffic']['value'];
 $query = "INSERT INTO intervaltime(intervalnumber,destinationname,originname,distancevalue,durationintrafficvalue,durationintraffictext) VALUES(:intervalnumber,:destination_addresses,:origin_addresses,:distance,:duration_in_traffic_value,:duration_in_traffic_text)";

$pdoResult = $db->prepare($query);

$pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(
"intervalnumber" => $intervalnumber,
"destination_addresses" => $destination_addresses,
"origin_addresses" => $origin_addresses,
"distance" => $distance,
"duration_in_traffic_value" => $duration_in_traffic_value,
"duration_in_traffic_text" => $duration_in_traffic_text
));

if ($pdoExec) {
echo("data Inserted!");
} else {
echo("Data not Inserted!");
}
```

/*
    $query = ("INSERT INTO intervaltime(database_parameters) VALUES('$intervalnumber','$destination_addresses','$origin_addresses','$distance','$duration_in_traffic_value','$duration_in_traffic_text')");
        $pdoResult = $db->prepare($query);
        $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute();
        if ($pdoExec) {
            echo('data Inserted!');
        } else {
            echo('Data not Inserted!');
        }
        //closing the database connect
        echo "
";
        echo "
";
        break;}}
        $db = null;
        ?>

Comment: what does the error say (which you should read out after execute)?

Comment: echo `$query` right before `$pdoResult`  --  What does it look like?

Comment: INSERT INTO intervaltime(intervalnumber,destinationname,originname,distancevalue,durationintrafficvalue,durationintraffictext) VALUES(1,Jinnah Avenue Underpass, Islamabad, Pakistan,Jinnah Avenue Underpass, Islamabad, Pakistan,999,47,1 min)Data not Inserted!

Comment: This is no error all the code is running just fine but data storing in db is random .. sometimes 1st value is inserted, sometimes 2nd value.. and some 1st and 2nd both.. but it does not store other than 1 and 2.

Comment: There are images up "
This is the data passing to the query but not inserted."

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try your request like this (using prepare, execute with external variables) :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO intervaltime(intervalnumber,destinationname,originname,distancevalue,durationintrafficvalue,durationintraffictext) VALUES(:intervalnumber,:destination_addresses,:origin_addresses,:distance,:duration_in_traffic_value,:duration_in_traffic_text)";

$pdoResult = $db->prepare($query);

$pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(
    "intervalnumber" => $intervalnumber,
    "destination_addresses" => $destination_addresses,
    "origin_addresses" => $origin_addresses,
    "distance" => $distance,
    "duration_in_traffic_value" => $duration_in_traffic_value,
    "duration_in_traffic_text" => $duration_in_traffic_text
    ));

if ($pdoExec) {
    echo("data Inserted!");
} else {
    echo("Data not Inserted!");
}
```

Also, be careful to use quotes on :

```
echo("data Inserted!");
```

It should work :)

Have a nice day,
André

Comment: thanks for your help but still I got data Inserted!
Data not Inserted!
Data not Inserted!
Data not Inserted!

Comment: @Ammarmoin can you please upload your full PHP code ?